# Combining duplicate rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, schema, aggregate

I've been tasked with cleaning data from a mobile application designed by a charity

In one section, a users Q/A app use session is represented by a row. This section consists of repeated question answer field pairs, where a field represents the question asked and then the field next to it represents the corresponding answer. Together, each question/field and answer column pair represent a unique question with the answer.

Starting data

[image: https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TUH1VSHL5-F01N4AHABJ7/image.png]

```
   answers.0.answer    answers.0.fieldName answers.1.answer    answers.1.fieldName
5   0                    avoidexercise             0.0            vomitflag
6   156                  height                    54.0         weight
7   1                    affectedkneeside           3.0       painlocationknee
```

I have been asked to reformat the section so each question forms a column, the corresponding answer a field in that column

The ideal output (image and code)

[image]

```
_id                    avoidexercise    enjoyment   fatigue2weeks   height
        

5f27f29c362a380d3f9a9e46    1.0           yes            20.0       120.0
5f27f2ac362a380d3f9a9e4b    0.0           no             40.0       180.0
5f27f4d4362a380d3f9a9e52    1.0           yes            50.0       150.0
```

My plan is to create many pivot tables, from each other Q/A pairs of columns, then concaternate (outer join) then inner join to remove duplications

However, the original dataframe contains a mixture of numeric and object datatypes

Therefore, only some question/answer column pairs  appear to be converting to pivot tables. I have tried using various aggregate functions

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p2 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.1.fieldName'],values=['answers.1.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p3 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.2.fieldName'],values=['answers.2.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

I have also tried another lamda function

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)
```

The furthest I have got so far is to run pivots with standard mean aggfunc

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns=['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'])
ps = [p1,p2,p3]
c = pd.concat(ps)
```

Then attempting to remove merge rows and columns

```
df = c.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)

g = df.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

This returns a dataframe with the right shape

However, it looses the values in the object columns, and I'm not sure how accurate all the numeric columns are

Comment: Hey Sam, take some time to read [ask] and [mcve] then please format your question with your input dataset as well as your expected output. You've showed your own research and effort which is great, but to help the community needs to be able to reproduce your dataset to give you an ideal solution. Don't take downvotes personally, its the way the community gives feedback when we need ot improve our questions & answers.

Comment: Can you provide some input data and specify how your output should look like ? it would be helpful for us.

Comment: Good idea guys, data attached as pngs above